# Values not passed correctly from parent to child

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular2 and for practice purposes I have created a set of 3 input components with a Reset button that erases the values entered. I wanted to test the @Input decorator and how values are passed from parent to children. The issue in my code is that the button erases the values only once

Here is the code, the parent component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <button (click)="reset()">Reset Age</button>
  <app-form-user [age]="age" [name]="name" [surname]="surname">
    </app-form-user>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name;
  surname;
  age;

  reset(){
    this.name = '';
    this.surname = '';
    this.age = 18;
  }
}
```

and the app-form-user component:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-user',
  template: `
    <form>
      <div>
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text" value={{name}}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Surname: </label>
        <input type="text" value={{surname}}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Age: </label>
        <input type="number" value={{age}} min="18" max="100"/>
      </div>
    </form>`,
  styleUrls: ['./form-user.component.css']
})
export class FormUserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() age;

  @Input() name;

  @Input() surname;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.age = 18;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular provide directive to bind some variable to input elements. I don't know why your reset button only works one time, but you should look at the `[(ngModel)]` directive from the `FormsModule`.

See [Two-way data binding with ngModel](https://angular.io/guide/forms#two-way-data-binding-with-ngmodel)

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Surname: </label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="surname"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Age: </label>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="age" min="18" max="100"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

And don't forget to import `FormsModule` in your component module.

Comment: Maybe the reference to the values provided to the component change on reset() and thats why it only works once?

Comment: The `@inputs` "age", "name" and "surname" seems to be literal, so I don't think there is reference issue. I think the issue came from the way the value are binded to the HTML input element, with simple one way binding

Comment: I thought about that as well. Maybe you're right. I remember somewhere in the docs it says something like, that theres a difference between properties and attributes and the way its handled by the dom.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind changes in the parent component to the child component:

**Parent HTML:**

```
  <app-form-user [(name)]="name"></app-form-user>
```

**Child HTML:**

```
 <input type="text" [ngModel]= "name" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)"/>
```

**Child class:**

```
  @Input() name;

  @Output() nameChange = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {
  }

  onModelChange(event) {        
    this.nameChange.emit(event);
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5qwh2v?file=app%2Fform.component.ts)**